# How can I register a secondary servlet with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an extra servlet I need to register in my application. However with Spring Boot and its Java Config, I can't just add servlet mappings in a `web.xml` file.

How can I add additional servlets?

Comment: I came up to this question just now, but if you don't mind, what will be the purpose to add other Servlets apart from the provided DispatcherServlet? You can use anyway multiple Controllers and whatever url/path you want

Comment: @aerox It has been many years... I can't recall the usecase I had at the time. Perhaps it was to leverage the DropWizard metric exporter servlet, since it offered a way to visualize the metric that had been collected. SpringBoot later incoporated that into an actuator endpoint itself. (And Micrometer.io solves the problem even better)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

[Just add a bean for the servlet](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-filters-listeners). It'll get mapped to `/{beanName}/`.

```
@Bean
public Servlet foo() {
    return new FooServlet();
}
```

Comment: Note that if you actually want it mapped to `/something/*` rather than `/something/` you will need to use `ServletRegistrationBean`.

Comment: This didn't work for me. What worked was the ServletRegistrationBean in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20939923/3165190

Comment: @peterh The snippet is as trivial as can be; I updated the stale link.

Comment: @chrylis Thanks, nice to see!

Answer (score 145):

Also available is the `ServletRegistrationBean`

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean(){
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(new FooServlet(),"/someOtherUrl/*");
}
```

Which ended up being the path I took.

Comment: how to add multiple servlets in ServletRegistrationBean?

Comment: @sakura You can't add multiple servlets. Do you mean multiple URLs?

Comment: @sakura Why would you want to register multiple servlets using the same registration bean? Just create multiple registration beans.

Comment: @MiladNaseri Actually I had multiple servlet filters and wanted to configure those filters using ServletRegistrationBean on different URLs. Or Same servlet configured on different unique urls not just all urls. Anyways I guess this was the requirement when I asked this question in comments. And I ended up applying that filter on all urls.

Comment: @Milad: Thanks for pointing this out. You should give this as official answer, then I would give you a point

Comment: @checketts - Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62081712/servletregistrationbean-doesnt-works-for-the-multiple-url-mapping-paths ?

Answer (score 22):

You can register multiple different servlet with different ServletRegistrationBean like @Bean in Application class and you can register a servlet has multiple servlet mapping;

```
   @Bean
   public ServletRegistrationBean axisServletRegistrationBean() {
      ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new AxisServlet(), "/services/*");
      registration.addUrlMappings("*.jws");
      return registration;
   }

   @Bean
   public ServletRegistrationBean adminServletRegistrationBean() {
      return new ServletRegistrationBean(new AdminServlet(), "/servlet/AdminServlet");
   }
```

Answer (score 6):

We can also register the Servlet as follow way:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigureWeb implements ServletContextInitializer, EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
      registerServlet(servletContext);
  }

  private void registerServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {
      log.debug("register Servlet");
      ServletRegistration.Dynamic serviceServlet = servletContext.addServlet("ServiceConnect", new ServiceServlet());

      serviceServlet.addMapping("/api/ServiceConnect/*");
      serviceServlet.setAsyncSupported(true);
      serviceServlet.setLoadOnStartup(2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using embedded server, you can annotate with `@WebServlet` your servlet class:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/example")
public class ExampleServlet extends HttpServlet
```

From [@WebServlet](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html):

> Annotation used to declare a servlet.
>
> This annotation is processed by the container at deployment time, and
>   the corresponding servlet made available at the specified URL
>   patterns.

And enable `@ServletComponentScan` on a base class:

```
@ServletComponentScan
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = { ExampleApp.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class })
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleApp
```

Please note that [@ServletComponentScan](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) will work only with embedded server:

> Enables scanning for Servlet components (filters, servlets, and
>   listeners). Scanning is only performed when using an embedded web
>   server.

More info: [The @ServletComponentScan Annotation in Spring Boot](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-servletcomponentscan)

Answer (score 2):

This way worked for me, having a servlet called WS01455501EndpointFor89

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<WS01455501EndpointFor89> servletRegistrationBeanAlt(ApplicationContext context) {
    ServletRegistrationBean<WS01455501EndpointFor89> servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new WS01455501EndpointFor89(),
            "/WS01455501Endpoint");
    servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    return servletRegistrationBean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also available in the BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor

```
package bj;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.RootBeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@SpringBootApplication
class App implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
        registry.registerBeanDefinition("myServlet", new RootBeanDefinition(ServletRegistrationBean.class,
                () -> new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new HttpServlet() {
                    @Override
                    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
                        resp.getWriter().write("hello world");
                    }
                }, "/foo/*")));
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
    }
}
```