# SpringFramework Boot reads input stream before other servlet can read it

Tags: java, servlets, spring-boot

I have an existing web application consisting of jsps and servlets that I am trying to add SpringFramework Boot to so that I can add some new simple rest services to the application. These rest services accept and return JSON through jackson-databind.

Problem is, in so doing, an existing servlet that reads uploaded files has it's request input stream now consumed before it gets called and thus the files are not there.

Using maven I have added the following to my pom.xml...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

... and I have added the following RestApplication class ...

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class RestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected final SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(RestApplication.class);
    }
}
```

... and the following controller class ...

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/obj/mycontroller")
public class MyController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public long save(final HttpServletRequest request,
                     final MyObject thing)
    {
        // save the thing
    }
}
```

... and that all works fine, **BUT** now my file upload standard servlet has broken. It still gets called, but it appears that its input stream is empty so that no files are found. Here is the definition of that servlet...

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

@MultipartConfig
public class MediaUploadServlet
    extends HttpServlet
{    
    protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request,
                          final HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
            DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            try {
                List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
                // do stuff with the files.
            } catch (FileUploadException ex) {
                // handle error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... and items is now empty.

If I take away the **@EnableAutoConfiguration** tag then the MediaUploadServlet works again but MyController does not. So my question is, how can I configure Spring Boot to **only** do it's magic on MyController or **not** do it's magic on MediaUploadServlet?

Comment: Register your secondary servlet like this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915528/how-can-i-register-a-secondary-servlet-with-spring-boot

Comment: If you answer it in the way I did I can vote for your answer and delete mine.

Comment: Answered as requested ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do register the servlet via a bean as follows in your RestApplication class

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean(){
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(new MediaUploadServlet(),"/mediaupload");
}
```