# Programmatic servlet registration in Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring-boot

I want to programmatically register servlet in Spring Boot 2 using embedded Tomcat.

I found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/register-servlet) that this is possible using `WebApplicationInitializer`. Later I realized that this approach does [not work with embedded Tomcat](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/522).

Comment: You are using Spring Boot, have you considered to read [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-filters-listeners-beans)?

Comment: I will revisit this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about using [ServletRegistrationBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/ServletRegistrationBean.html)?

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean(){
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(new FooServlet(),"/someOtherUrl/*");
}
```

Comment: I guess this question is kind of a duplicate :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/20939923/2400849

Comment: If you mean answer, then yes. But is that answer to your question or are you asking about something different?

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks for your feedback.