# Set different context paths with configuration files

Tags: java, spring-boot

Set Context path differently for both Webservice and Rest

I have an application which contains both implementation of Webservices and Rest services and I am looking for an solution to set context path for both Webservices and Rest services differently using yml/properties file

How to configure servlet dispatcher to work properly?

I would like to have:

```
localhost:8080/ws/* - webservice
localhost:8080/web/* - MVC components
```

```
  servlet:
    context-path: "/ws"
```

It sets globally for both webservices and rest services , How to make it independent to each other with out programming?

Comment: Did you try to use Nginx (or alternative) proxy routing method?

Comment: I don't believe you can. You would need to programmitcally created 2 servlets and configure each one to map to a context path. See this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915528/how-can-i-register-a-secondary-servlet-with-spring-boot/20915584

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring Boot (with Spring Starter Web) you could achive what are you asking for with the annotation @RequestMapping.

You could put @RequestMapping(value="/ws") on the class declaration of every rest controller and @RequestMapping(value="/web") for web controllers.

For both rest and web controller than you could use other annotations to specify method path, i.e @GetMapping(value="/methodPath").

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/web")
public class WebController{

    @GetMapping(value="/method")
    public String method(){
        ...
    }

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/ws")
public class RestController{

    @GetMapping(value="method")
    public String method(){
        ...
    }

}
```