# How to add ckfinder in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-java/latest/guides/quick-start.html

```
<!-- web.xml -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CKFinder</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.cksource.ckfinder.servlet.CKFinderServlet</servlet-class>
    <multipart-config>
        <location>/tmp</location>
        <max-file-size>5242880</max-file-size><!--5MB-->
        <max-request-size>20971520</max-request-size><!--20MB-->
        <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
</servlet>
```

I'm trying to install ckfinder to upload images to ckditor5, but I have the following problem.The official document says Enable the CKFinder servlet in your configuration, but there is no web.xml file in the Spring Boot environment, so I don't know how to apply this. Can you help? ?

The following work has already been completed

```
1. Add CKSource Maven Repository to your project
Gradle

// build.gradle
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = 'https://maven.cksource.com/'
    }
}
```

```
2. Add CKFinder in project dependencies
Gradle

// build.gradle
dependencies {
    compile 'com.cksource:ckfinder3:3.5.1.1'
}
```

The page to be applied is as follows

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <title> SpringBoot : makePerson </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <style>
        .ck.ck-editor {
            max-width: 500px;
        }
        .ck-editor__editable {
            min-height: 300px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/11.0.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div style="text-align: center">
    <h1>make page</h1>
    <form  th:action="@{/createDiary}" th:object="${Diary}" method="post" id="content" name="content">
        <p>writer : <input type="text" th:field="*{writer}"/></p>
        <p>title : <input type="text" th:field="*{title}"/></p>
        <p style="position: relative; left: 720px"><textarea name="context" id="editor" type="text" th:field="*{content}"/></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="add"/> <input type="reset" value="reset"/></p>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        } );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915528/how-can-i-register-a-secondary-servlet-with-spring-boot on how to register a servlet in Spring Boot.